# Splice arraylist in Java and group the second part

Tags: java, arraylist, sublist

I have a List of Dto, composed by 'userName' and 'skills'. For example:
userName: "John", skills: 5

If there are more than 5 elements (so 5 users) I'd like to maintaining the top five, and grouping the other under one name ('Others') and under one skill (the sum of all the skills). I thought of using the sublist method, create two temporary array, group the dto of the second array and merge all in the main Arraylist. 
This is my code but it doesn't work. Why?

```
final List<MyDto> usersData = mydao.getUsers();
List<MyDto> result = new ArrayList<MyDto>();    


if (usersData != null && usersData.size() > 0) {
    List<MyDto> tmpFirstFiveUsers = new ArrayList<MyDto>();

    List<MyDto> tmpOthers = new ArrayList<MyDto>();


    if(usersData.size() > 5) {
        // Save first 5 users
        tmpFirstFiveUsers = usersData.subList(0, 5);

        // Save others
        tmpOthers = usersData.subList(5, usersData.size());

        // Sum of 'others' skill
        int skills = 0;
        for (MyDto other : tmpOthers) {
            skills += other.getSkills();
        }

        String other = "Altro";

        MyDto emptyDto = new MyDto();
        emptyDto.setUserName(other);
        emptyDto.setSkills(skills);

        tmpOthers.clear();

        tmpOthers.add(emptyDto);
      } 

        result.clear();

        result.addAll(tmpFirstFiveUsers);
        result.addAll(tmpOthers);
```

UPDATE:
I can't do correctly the sublist, it doesn't work.
I give also an example to understand:
usersData:

- userName: "a", skills: "2"
- userName: "b", skills: "1"
- userName: "c", skills: "5"
- userName: "d", skills: "5"
- userName: "e", skills: "5"
- userName: "f", skills: "5"
- userName: "g", skills: "5"
- userName: "h", skills: "5"
- userName: "i", skills: "5"

What I expected is:
usersData:

- userName: "a", skills: "2"
- userName: "b", skills: "1"
- userName: "c", skills: "5"
- userName: "d", skills: "5"
- userName: "e", skills: "5"
- userName: "Others", skills: "20"

Comment: `it doesn't work` - remember to be specific about that. What do you get? What did you expect, if possible with an example?

Comment: the last 3 statements should be inside the `if` condition otherwise `tmpFirstFiveUsers` and `tmpOthers` would be empty lists.

Comment: Btw, if your list contains 5 or less users `tmpFirstFiveUsers` will be empty - at least that's what your code indicates.

Comment: correct your code and handle both the conditions when there is 5 or less users or more than 5 users.

Comment: for (MyDto other : tmpOthers) {

Comment: look the update, i've written an example

Comment: Your example is still incomplete. What do you get with your code? Also keep in mind that sublists are backed by the original list, thus ` tmpOthers.clear();` will remove all corresponding entries from `usersData`. If you don't want this create new lists and pass the sublists as constructor parameters.

Comment: in result.addAll(tmpFirstFiveUsers) console writes: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [`List#sublist()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) returns *a view* of the list, so all modifications performed in a sublist are reflected in that "parent" list. That is why you get unpredicted results. To operate sublists safely, you should **copy** items:

```
tmpFirstFiveUsers = new ArrayList<>(usersData.subList(0, 5));
tmpOthers = new ArrayList<>(usersData.subList(5, usersData.size()));
```